# How to call IntersectionObserver Call back function from jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, intersection-observer

Js code for new Intersection Observer for lazy image load.

```
_observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        let lazyImage = entry.target;
        lazyImage.removeAttribute('class');
        _observer.unobserve(lazyImage);
      }
    });
```

jest code:

```
 beforeAll(() => {
  const options = {
    threshold: 0.1,
  };

  window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn(function () {
    observe, unobserve;
  }, options);

  wrapper = mount(<Image url="test.jpg" alt="test" />);
});

afterAll(() => {
  window.IntersectionObserver = windowIntersectionObserver;
});
 it('creates an observer on the element ref', () => {
  expect(observe).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

o/p :

```
  Expected number of calls: >= 1
  Received number of calls:    0
```

This is not working for me. How to call the intersection observer from Jest code. I checked similar questions it's not worked here

Comment: Where did you call `new IntersectionObserver()` in your react component? Besides, you cannot access `_observer` before initialization